# How does `===` work?

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

I took a look on the Ruby on Rails source code and found code like this:

```
case options
when /\A([a-z][a-z\d\-+\.]*:|\/\/).*/i
  ...
when String
  ...
when :back
  ...
when Proc
  ...
end
```

where `options` can be a `String`, `Symbol`, `Proc`, or `Hash` object. The `===` comparison will return `true` only in one case:

```
'string' === /string/ # => false
:back === :back # => true
(Proc.new {}) === Proc # => nil
Hash.new === Hash # => false
```

How does Ruby `case` work, allowing match with such different cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A wrong assumption that you (as well as many beginners) seem to make is that `===` is symmetric. It actually is not. `x === y` works differently not depending on `y`, but depending on `x`.

Different classes have different definitions for `===`. The expression `x === y` is the same as:

- `y == x` (for `x`: instance of `String`, `Symbol`, `Hash`, etc.)
- `y =~ x`(for `x`: instance of `Regexp`)
- `y.kind_of?(x)` (for `x`: instance of `Class`)

Also, you may be confusing a class and its instance. `/regexp/ ===` is not the same as `Regexp ===`. `"string" ===` is not the same as `String ===`, etc.

Comment: The operand order can also be confusing. `case obj; when pattern; end` invokes `pattern === obj`, not `obj === pattern`.

Answer (score 3):

It might help to understand that:

```
"foo" === /foo/
```

is actually another way to write:

```
"foo".===(/foo/)
```

So it's actually a method call to the instance method [`String#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) on `"foo"` (which is an instance of class `String`), passing it `/foo/` as the argument. Therefore what will happen is totally defined by `String#===`.

In your code, what actually happens is this:

```
if /\A([a-z][a-z\d\-+\.]*:|\/\/).*/i === options
  # ...
elsif String === options
  # ...
elsif :back === options
  # ...
elsif Proc === options
  # ...
else
  # ...
end.delete("\0\r\n")
```

Therefore your `case` statements are actually method calls to (in order of appearance):

1. [`Regex#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)
2. [`Module#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)
3. [`Symbol#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)
4. and then again [`Module#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)

Regarding the second example in your question:

```
'string' === /string/ # => false
```

This above is calling [`String#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) which, according to the documentation:

> Returns whether str == obj, similar to Object#==.
>
> If obj is not an instance of String but responds to to_str, then the
>   two strings are compared using case equality Object#===.
>
> Otherwise, returns similarly to #eql?, comparing length and content.

That's why it doesn't match, because it actually calls `Object#==`.

Similarly:

```
# this calls `Proc#===`, not `Module#===`
(Proc.new {}) === Proc # => false

# however, if you want to test for class equality you should do:
Proc === (Proc.new {}) # => true, calls `Module#===`
```

Same goes for `Hash.new === Hash`.